# Hide element when clicked anywhere outside

Tags: jquery

Yes this question has been asked before, but it didn't solve my problem.

So consider this situation, say i have a div let's call it `container`, now this div contains **a lot** of other various objects like `<a>, <img />, <div>, <ul>` well you get the point...

Now, user can do stuff in that div, write messages etc... but when he clicks anywhere outside that `container` element it should dissapear, so that's simple right?

```
$(document).on("click", document, function(event){
    if($(event.target).is(".container")) return;
    $(".container").hide();
});
```

Well indeed this would work and at the same time not, since it would only check if the target is not `container`, if you would click say on some button it would dissapear as well, well i could just include every single element in that `if` statement, oh but in my case it would be a very very long list... so there has to be a better way

And yes i did try to use `event.stopPropagation()` but it didn't work, i guess it's because i'm using `on` instead of simple `click` event, please help me out with this...

Also I have setup this fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/nVfJ5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `closest()` method. By definition it starts with the target and works up the tree to find a match. So if the element is the selector it will stop.

```
if($(event.target).closest(".container").length) return;
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

The `document` is always available, so there's no need for a delegated event handler?

Just check if the `event.target` has a `.container` element as a parent somewhere, if not hide the `.container` element:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).closest(".container").length)
        $(".container").hide();
});
```